# Sort Dictionary Keys in natural order

Tags: python, dictionary, natural-sort

I want to sort dictionary keys in a "natural order". If I have a dictionary with the keys

```
    d = {"key1" : object, "key11" : object, "key2" : object, "key22" : object", "jay1" : object, "jay2" : object}
```

I want to sort this dictionary so the result is:

```
    d = { "jay1" : object, "jay2" : object, "key_1" : object, "key_2" : object, "key_11" : object, "key_22" : object"}
```

Comment: Use https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

Comment: Dictionaries are not ordered.  You can't control the order of dictionary keys.

Comment: Are you asking how to "sort the dictionary" (in which case the question is a duplicate) or how to sort (anything) by natural order (pretty sure it's a duplicate anyway)?

Comment: I don't believe this is a duplicate, because the question it is marked a duplicate of is about standard sorting, while this question is about natural sorting.

Comment: Should be reopened as it is about sorting by natural order, which is what I found this question for when googling.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of *"How to I sort a dictionary by key"*, because this question states that it's about **natural order** in the title and in the body of the question with an appropriate example. Normal (default) sorting would shuffle keys in a different way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change your dict into [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#ordereddict-examples-and-recipes):

```
import collections, re

d = {"key1" : 'object', "key11" : 'object', "key2" : 'object', "key22" : 'object', "jay1" : 'object', "jay2" : 'object'}


my_fun = lambda k,v: [k, int(v)]

d2 = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda t: my_fun(*re.match(r'([a-zA-Z]+)(\d+)',t[0]).groups())))

print(d2)
#reslt: OrderedDict([('jay1', 'object'), ('jay2', 'object'), ('key1', 'object'), ('key11', 'object'), ('key2', 'object'), ('key22', 'object')])
```

Basically, what is happening here, that I split the strings into 'string' part and number part. Number part is changed to `int`, and the sorting happens using these two values.

Comment: This does not sort the keys in natural order.

Comment: @user2909250 Sorry, I amended example to include the missing "natural" order.

Comment: You could avoid the long `lambda` and regex by using `natsort.natsorted`.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, dictionaries are not ordered. However, if you want to iterate through these keys in a natural order, you could do something like the following:

```
d = {"key1" : object, "key11" : object, "key2" : object, "key22" : object, "jay1" : object, "jay2" : object}
sortedKeys = sorted(d.keys())
print sortedKeys
for key in sortedKeys:
    print d[key]
```

Comment: It is not natrual order. Natural order is when the string "key11" goes after the string "key2".

Answer (score 1):

You can't order `dictionaries` because their order is **seemingly** arbitrary (it's actually not). Instead, you can sort the `items()` using [`natsort.natsorted()`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/natsort):

```
d = {"key1" : object, "key11" : object, "key2" : object, "key22" : object, "jay1" : object, "jay2" : object}
print natsort.natsorted(d.items()) #[('jay1', <type 'object'>), ('jay2', <type 'object'>), ('key1', <type 'object'>), ('key2', <type 'object'>), ('key11', <type 'object'>), ('key22', <type 'object'>)]
```

Comment: This does not sort the keys in natural order.

Comment: @user2909250 now it does :)

Answer (score 0):

In Python, `{'a': object, 'b': object}` is exactly the same as `{'b': object, 'a': object}` because dictionaries are not ordered.